# how to Automatically calculate expiry date in backpack laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

i have a field which name is month what i want is when user set the month it automatic calculate with **created at** month and then upload it to database.

> PS - sorry i am new at laravel

Please see Edit:

my store method looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

 // VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need 
form validation
use App\Http\Requests\ClientsRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ClientsRequest as UpdateRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon; 

class ClientsCrudController extends CrudController
{
public function setup()
{

    $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Clients');
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/clients');
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('clients', 'clients');

    $this->crud->setFromDb();

}

public function store(StoreRequest $request)
{
    // your additional operations before save here


    $start_day = Carbon::parse($request->created_at);
    $expiry_day = $start_day->addMonths($request->month);
    $request->input($expiry_day);

    $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}

public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    // your additional operations after save here
    // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate with a month and the created_at field? Please give an example.

Comment: actually sir, i have a column in my table which name is created_at and i have other column which is expire_at ... so when new user register backpack automatic fill the create_at column so like that i have to fill expire_at column which depend on user month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean months ammount ( i.e for a monthly payment )

You can do it like this in your store method i.e:

```
$start_day = Carbon::parse($request->created_at); //get a carbon instance with created_at as date
$expiry_day = $start_day->addMonths($request->user_selected_months); //add X months to created_at date
```

Comment: tell me your email id sir .. i will send you my project over there

Comment: which field shows null? sorry I think it isn't alowed by site rules

Comment: Update your question with your actual controller method code

Comment: the variable `$request->month` is a single mont? as july? or it is a months amount ? like 5 months. Which variable showed you null? I don't understand this line `$request->input($expiry_day);` what is supposed to happen here?

Comment: it just a try forget about that sir

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function store(StoreRequest $request) {

    date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
    $month = $request->month;       
    $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($month);            
    $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;

    }
```